# Sharepoint choice field validation is not working?

Tags: sharepoint

`[department]<>"select"`
I have tried this code but it is not working and also not giving the output as accepted.

`> [department]<>"select"`

Comment: `this code … is not working and also not giving the output as accepted` lo and behold! Please edit into your question: What, if anything, gets output and what, in contrast, would be accepted? See [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your isse.

Test result:[image]